# Views inside container aren't resizing correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I've been trying to solve this issue for the past couple of hours, searched SO and still to no avail.

I have a UIViewController which has a Container view inside (dragged in from Storyboards). The container view has a class associated that picks one of two other view controllers to display.

```
-(void)setDisplayMode:(EventsDisplayMode)displayMode {
switch (displayMode) {
    case EventsDisplayModeGrid: {
        // show grid
        if (!gridViewController) {
            gridViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gridViewController"];
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
            if (listViewController)
                [listViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            gridViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            [self.view addSubview:gridViewController.view];
            listViewController = nil;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        break;
    }
    case EventsDisplayModeList: {
        // show list
        if (!listViewController)
            listViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listViewController"];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
            if (gridViewController)
                [gridViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:listViewController.view];
            gridViewController = nil;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        }];


        break;
    }
}
}
```

The above is the code in the container view controller. When either mode is set though, the view bleeds off the bottom of the screen on an iPhone 5s slightly, and on an iPhone 4S it's as though the view inside hasn't resized at all for the device. I've tried all sorts of combinations to resize the views - setting up constrains inside Storyboards for each of the controllers, manually taking off amounts from the height of views - nothing seems to work. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say "setting up constraints" as you're using the autoresizingMask. Presumably you're using auto-layout? Then don't reference the resizing mask. What are the constraints you've set?

Comment: The constraints set are 0 spacing to top, right, left and bottom for the content of each view controller (so as not to fix height). When I switch from Retina 4 form to Retina 3.5 (in Xcode), all views resize as expected. It's just when the program runs that problems occur

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after you've set up the views, you can use po [listViewController constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis: 1] to print out all the current constraints